# difference between static and normal java libraries in android make file

Tags: android

Can LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES be used instead of LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES in Android.mk file?
Build cook book (http://pdk.android.com/online-pdk/guide/build_cookbook.html#mkVars) doesn't give information about LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES. what is the difference between static and regular java libraries.

Answer (score 4):

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES are used for libraries which will be clubbed with your library or jar. Similar to lib.a.
LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES are used for libraries which won't be clubbed with your jar. Similar to lib.so. For LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES platform should provide its implementation else it would crash.